# How to specify sbt dependency along with the intended JDK version

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

How do I specify the JDK version of a dependency in my `Build.sbt`?

I encounter such a case with the Aspose library, where the filename is postfixed with JDK version, i.e. `aspose-email-4.8.0-jdk17.jar` instead of the plain `aspose-email-4.8.0.jar`. So, specifying the dependency normally, e.g.

```
"com.aspose" % "aspose-email" % "4.8.0"
```

will cause sbt to complain with the following error, as the poor SBT tries to download a non-existing file:

```
[warn]  [FAILED     ] com.aspose#aspose-email;4.8.0!aspose-email.jar:  (0ms)
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/developer/.ivy2/local/com.aspose/aspose-email/4.8.0/jars/aspose-email.jar
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/aspose/aspose-email/4.8.0/aspose-email-4.8.0.jar
[warn] ==== Aspose: tried
[warn]   http://maven.aspose.com/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local/com/aspose/aspose-email/4.8.0/aspose-email-4.8.0.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.aspose#aspose-email;4.8.0!aspose-email.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.aspose#aspose-email;4.8.0!aspose-email.jar
```

**Update**
Then I figured that appending the JDK version to the version number might fix it:

```
"com.aspose" % "aspose-email" % "4.8.0-jdk17"
```

Unfortunately it will to another error caused by SBT thinking the POM file is located at `aspose-email-4.8.0-jdk17.pom`, while it should instead be `aspose-email-4.8.0.pom`.

```
[info] Resolving com.aspose#aspose-email;4.8.0-jdk17 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.aspose#aspose-email;4.8.0-jdk17
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/ganeshwara/.ivy2/local/com.aspose/aspose-email/4.8.0-jdk17/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/aspose/aspose-email/4.8.0-jdk17/aspose-email-4.8.0-jdk17.pom
[warn] ==== Aspose: tried
[warn]   http://maven.aspose.com/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local/com/aspose/aspose-email/4.8.0-jdk17/aspose-email-4.8.0-jdk17.pom
[info] Resolving net.sf.proguard#proguard-base;5.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.aspose#aspose-email;4.8.0-jdk17: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]    com.aspose:aspose-email:4.8.0-jdk17 (/Users/ganeshwara/DropMyEmail/backup-server/project/Build.scala#L290)
[warn]      +- Dropmysite:common_2.11:1.0-296020c84e74fa1fd65cd5361b563519ff9c4a5d
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.aspose#aspose-email;4.8.0-jdk17: not found
```

I think if you look into the [repo](http://maven.aspose.com/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local/com/aspose/aspose-email/4.8.0/), you'll see that the problem is due to differing naming convention - where the jarfile is postfixed with the intended JDK version but the POM file is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, I've found that Maven actually has an optional extra coordinate, the **classifier**, which is appended just after the version number ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909695/900130)).

To use it in sbt, you should define your dependency as

```
"com.aspose" % "aspose-email" % "4.8.0" classifier "jdk17"
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579444/900130))

Comment: @lolski where are you getting this dependency from? it's on on maven central

Comment: It's on http://maven.aspose.com/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local, more specifically, http://maven.aspose.com/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local/com/aspose/aspose-email/4.8.0/